# Linq Get Max from List of Records

Tags: linq

I have the following table

```
ID Amt  Received  SchoolAmt
-- ---- --------  -------
2  55   N          
2  88   Y          7
2  44   N          6  
3  5    N
3  9    N
4  5    N          32
5  33   Y
6  43   N
7  54   N          66
```

For a given ID, I need to find the Max Amount and then check to see if it is Marked as Y, if so, mark the result as boolean true of false.

One way to do this would be:

```
    db.Exp.
    Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amt)
    .Take(1)
    .Any(x => x.Received == "Y");
```

which works but I also need to add that SchoolAmt should also be greater than 0.

Why is the following not working:

```
    db.Exp.
    Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amt)
    .Take(1)
    .Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x => x.SchoolAmt > 0);
```

When I try to type in x => x.SchoolAmt > 0 Visual studio does not allow it as it seems to be the incorrect syntex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate should be written as:

```
.Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x.SchoolAmt > 0);
```

This is a single delegate, which gets mapped to a function that looks something similar to:

```
static bool someCompilerGeneratedName(YourClass x)
{
    return x.Received == "Y" && x.SchoolAmt > 0; 
}
```

Since this is a single delegate, and a single method, you only need the `=>` in there at the beginning to create the lambda.  The two criteria checks use the same variable (x).

Comment: how do I know when to use && x.SchoolAmt > 0 vs. what I had. Meaning, I have seen something like x => x.Received == "Y" && x => x.SchoolAmt > 0 used in the where clause before

Comment: @Nate The "x =>" is making a lambda expression.  It's basically causing the compiler to create a method for you.  The "x" is the argument to the method, and everything after that is what's included in the method body.  You only use that once per predicate (at the beginning).

Comment: @NatePet The compiler turns the first code block in my answer into something similar to the second - "x =>" is mapped to the "(YourClass x)" parameter list of the method it makes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x.SchoolAmt > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the MoreLinq library via Nuget this will give you the MaxBy/MinBy extensions, then using the following

```
 db.Exp.
    Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .MaxBy(x => x.Amt)
    .Any(x => x.Received == "Y" && x.SchoolAmt > 0);
```